# How to "Get" the value of COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT?

Tags: php, bash, composer-php

i'm using a `Script` bash file to define the composer `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT` variable, but before set its value, i need to know what is the previusly seted value.

I've been searching in the internet looking for something maybe like, but I can't find anything similar. Not even in the Composer documentation.

Setting the `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT`

```sh
    setComposerProcessTimeout(){
        echo "Defining the COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT = 2000"
        composer --global config process-timeout 2000
    }
```

How to get the `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT` and use in a if like above:

```sh
    COMPOSER_TIMEOUT_VALUE = #(I dont kown how to get).

    if !${COMPOSER_TIMEOUT_VALUE} == 300 ; then
      echo ${COMPOSER_TIMEOUT_VALUE}
    fi
```

Comment: I Hav eused this in a bat file in windows over wsl

Comment: And you use in a Makefile too, I recommend

Answer (score 1):

In this case I needed to get the value using:

```sh
COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT_VALUE=$(composer --global config process-timeout)
```

and then in the if I use

```sh
setComposerProcessTimeout() {

    if [[ "${COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT_VALUE}" = "2000" ]]; then
        echo "Defining COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT to 2000"
        composer --global config process-timeout 2000
    fi
    exit
}
```

In that way I can get and compare the variable.

Comment: We can make a Makefile to use this info maybe change the value

Comment: Some times a Makefile is better than use this as a bat in windows.